# is there a way to remove the formula and have the value result if a condition is met in excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

I'm working on the workbook where I'm using vlookup formula to get the result from the other table. Also, I have the status field which has values Open and Closed. The vlookup formula should work when the status is open and it should freeze the value when the status is closed

---

EX:

1. I have the status open for both ID 1 and 2 and it's referring the vlookup table:

---

```
ID Status Amount
----------------
1   Open    100
2   Open    200
```

**Vlookup Table**

```
ID Amount
---------
 1  100 
 2  200
```

---

2. The status for ID 1 is updated to "Closed", so at this point I want to freeze the value in the Amount Column:

---

```
ID Status Amount
----------------
1   Closed  100
2   Open    200
```

**Vlookup Table**

```
ID Amount
---------
 1  100 
 2  200
```

---

3. A new row is added and the ID is 1 with the status "Open", and also the amount for this id in the vlookup table is updated to "50". The new row should reflect this updated value but the existing row with ID 1 will have the frozen value, as the existing row for ID 1 has the status "Closed" and the new row for ID 1 has the status "Open":

---

```
ID Status Amount
----------------
1   Closed  100
2   Open    200
1   Open    50
```

**Vlookup Table**

```
ID Amount
---------
 1  50
 2  200
```

Comment: you will need vba in a worksheet change event to remove the formula and paste back the value when the ID changed to "Closed"

Comment: Use VBA and the `Worksheet_Change` or `Worksheet_Calculate` event, depending on whether the status field is a value or a formula.